# How to check if the the difference of and number and a value from my object in my array is smaller than 100?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, var

I need to access an object and it's property and check if the the value of the property smaller than 100 is.

My code would look like following:

```
    let myArr = [{
    id: 1,
    x: 120,
    y: 150,
    }, {
    id: 2,
    x: 170,
    y: 420,
    }, {
    id: 3,
    x: 160,
    y: 220,
    }, {
    id: 4,
    x: 140,
    y: 170,

}];
    if(nearestEnemy.x - /*go throught all of my "x"-properties*/ && nearestEnemy.y - /*go throught all of my "y"-properties*/ < 100){
    
    }
```

You don't need to matter about the other code, just look at my comments.

I want to check if the x axis and the y axis is almost the same as of one of my properties from my object in my array.

I guess you'd need something like a loop for this but I can't think of anything!

I don't know if you can understand me because I cant really explain what I mean.

Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Comment: You can't loop inside the condition of the if. You have to loop over the array and check for each item separately

Comment: Do you want to find all object in the array that contain x and y properties and their difference is less than 100, right? And what do you do with that found object?

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov I want to check if the x and y axis of the enemy and my trap is only 100 off.
What I want to do, doesnt really matter i guess.

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov I guess its logical but still thank you!

Comment: @W4IT I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that ? I hope that will help you in understanding the use case and will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by filtering out the objects by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
let myArr = [{
  id: 1,
  x: 120,
  y: 150
}, {
  id: 2,
  x: 170,
  y: 420
}, {
  id: 3,
  x: 160,
  y: 220
}, {
  id: 4,
  x: 140,
  y: 170
}];

function difference(a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a - b);
}

const filtered = myArr.filter(({x, y}) => difference(x, y) < 100);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Remember to use Math.Abs for the `x - y` part. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs The documentation actually uses diff as the example :)

Comment: @CasperBang Thanks for pointing that out. It's very useful. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have an array of points and want to find an element which is the nearest to the given point. If this is the case, you can proceed like this:

- write a function that computes distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between two points
- write a loop that minimizes distance

Example:

```js
let myArr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        x: 120,
        y: 150,
    }, {
        id: 2,
        x: 170,
        y: 420,
    }, {
        id: 3,
        x: 160,
        y: 220,
    }, {
        id: 4,
        x: 140,
        y: 170,

    }];


function distance(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt(
        (p1.x - p2.x) ** 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ** 2,
    )
}


function nearestPoint(points, somePoint) {
    let min = +Infinity,
        minPt = null;

    for (let p of points) {
        let d = distance(p, somePoint);
        if (d < min) {
            min = d;
            minPt = p;
        }
    }

    return minPt;
}


console.log(nearestPoint(myArr, {x: 190, y: 130}))
```

This is not very efficient, but should be fine for < 10,000 points. If you have more, you'll need some kind of spatial indexing.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use this method if I don't find another, maybe easier.